# How to continue processing next items on exception for the following code snippet?

Tags: java, error-handling, nullpointerexception, rx-java2

When I run the code, the output coming is as follows

(a)Test(a=100)

(b)error here- java.lang.NullPointerException

In the current output, whenever the second item throws an exception, the flowable stop processing. But I want to process the third object like these

(a)Test(a=100)

(b)error here {} java.lang.NullPointerException

(c)Test(a=200)

```
public class Test {
    Integer a;

    public Integer getA() {
        return a * 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test(10);
        Test test2 = new Test(null); //this object throws exception when it enters flowable
        Test test3 = new Test(20);

        List<Test> strings = Arrays.asList(test, test2, test3);

        Flowable.fromCallable(() -> strings)
            .flatMap(s -> Flowable.fromIterable(s)
                .flatMap(a -> {
                    System.out.println(a);
                    return Flowable.just(a);
                })
                .onErrorResumeNext(r -> {
                    System.out.println("error here " + r);
                    return Flowable.empty();
                })
            )
            .onErrorResumeNext(s -> {
                return Flowable.empty();
            })
           .subscribe();
    }`
}
```

I tried above approach but does not work.

Comment: Why you don't want filter `Test(null)` items? That should solve your problem without any complicated error handling

Comment: Here, Test(null) is just for example. I am facing an exception where I can't add a filter. So, I need to handle exception when it comes and continue processing other items

Comment: There is overloaded [`flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends ObservableSource<? extends R>> mapper,
        boolean delayErrors)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-boolean-) that allows delay errors . You can pass delayErros = true in that case.